# Javascript - Need to get x and y coordinates only from the stroke of a SVG path?

Tags: javascript, html, svg, coordinates, mouse

I have a canvas in which, is drawn an element svg (example a circle), the user is responsible for drawing with the mouse through this figure, I save the dots x and y drawn by the user in an array, but I dont know how to get the dots only from svg stroke.

**My problem is:**
Using isPointInStroke() I can see if the point is in the stroke but If I don't have the total points array of the stroke, it's impossible to know if the user has drawn 100% of the SVG figure. In the previous way if the user draws half of the drawing but correctly, it would give me 100% success.

```
function init() {
    canvas = document.getElementById('can');
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    w = canvas.width;
    h = canvas.height;

    var svgPathCirculo=" M125,200a75,75 0 1,0 150,0a75,75 0 1,0 -150,0";
    var circulo = new Path2D(svgPathCirculo);
    ctx.lineWidth = 5;
    ctx.setLineDash([5, 15]);
    ctx.stroke(circulo);

    // Just example to check if it works
    if(ctx.isPointInStroke(circulo, 125, 200)){
      ctx.arc(200,200,3,0,2*Math.PI);
      ctx.fill();
    };

    canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function (e) {
        findxy('move', e)
    }, false);
    canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function (e) {
        findxy('down', e)
    }, false);
    canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", function (e) {
        findxy('up', e)
    }, false);
    canvas.addEventListener("mouseout", function (e) {
        findxy('out', e)
    }, false);
}
```

I use the canvas to draw on it and  svg to display predefined shapes for the user to follow as a template while drawing (such as drawing booklets for young children).

```
 function draw() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(prevX, prevY);
    ctx.lineTo(currX, currY);
    ctx.strokeStyle = x;
    ctx.lineWidth = y;
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();
}
function findxy(res, e) {
    if (res == 'down') {
        prevX = currX;
        prevY = currY;
        currX = e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
        currY = e.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;

        if(!arrayCoordenadas.includes({x:currX,y:currY})){
          arrayCoordenadas.push({x:currX,y:currY});
        }


        flag = true;
        dot_flag = true;
        if (dot_flag) {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.fillStyle = x;
            ctx.fillRect(currX, currY, 2, 2);
            ctx.closePath();
            dot_flag = false;
        }
    }
    if (res == 'up' || res == "out") {
        flag = false;
    }
    if (res == 'move') {
        if (flag) {
            prevX = currX;
            prevY = currY;
            currX = e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
            currY = e.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;
            if(!arrayCoordenadas.includes({x:currX,y:currY})){
              arrayCoordenadas.push({x:currX,y:currY});
            }
            draw();
        }
    }
}
```

**I need to know each of the x and y coordinates of the svg stroke path.**

Example: [Example of what I mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYOU4.png)

Comment: I'm confused: you tag your question SVG and then you talk about canvas and [isPointInPath()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/isPointInPath) - a method of the canvas's context. Can you add some code. A working example would be great.

Comment: Now the question is better formed, thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 1):

I've added a function to detect the mouse position in the canvas and now  currX became curr.x ... etc

If you are using `Path2D`this is how you detect if a point {x,y} is in the stroke:

```
ctx.isPointInStroke(the_path, x, y)
```

Next comes my code. The user can draw only inside the stroke.

*Now the code is working but I don't think you may know if the user has drawn 100% of the SVG figure*. You may push the points inside the array of points and calculate the length of the path, and compare it with the length of the circle, but I don't think this would do.

```js
let prev = {},
  curr = {};
let flag = false;
let circulo;

function init() {
  canvas = document.getElementById("can");
  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  w = canvas.width = 400;
  h = canvas.height = 400;

  var svgPathCirculo = "M125,200a75,75 0 1,0 150,0a75,75 0 1,0 -150,0";
  circulo = new Path2D(svgPathCirculo);

  ctx.lineWidth =10;
  ctx.setLineDash([5, 15]);
  ctx.stroke(circulo);

  canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", move, false);
  canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", down, false);
  canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", up, false);
  canvas.addEventListener("mouseout", up, false);
}

function draw(prev, curr, trazado) {
  
  ctx.setLineDash([]); //unset linedash
  ctx.lineCap = "round";
  ctx.strokeStyle = "gold"
  ctx.lineWidth =5;
  if (
    ctx.isPointInStroke(trazado, curr.x, curr.y) &&
    ctx.isPointInStroke(trazado, prev.x, prev.y)
  ) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(prev.x, prev.y);
    ctx.lineTo(curr.x, curr.y);
    ctx.stroke();
  }
}

function down(e) {
  prev = oMousePos(canvas, e);
  curr = oMousePos(canvas, e);

  flag = true;
  
}

function up(e) {
  flag = false;
}

function move(e) {
  if (flag) {
    curr = oMousePos(canvas, e);
    draw(prev, curr, circulo);
    prev = { x: curr.x, y: curr.y };
  }
}

function oMousePos(canvas, evt) {
  var ClientRect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  return {
    //objeto
    x: Math.round(evt.clientX - ClientRect.left),
    y: Math.round(evt.clientY - ClientRect.top)
  };
}

init();
```

```css
canvas{border:1px solid}
```

```html
<canvas id="can"></canvas>
```